# Which tools can help limit maximum page view per IP to limit scrapers and bots?

Tags: php, html

good evening. i'm searching for a tool to limit maximum page view per IP or to limit something in this page to be viewed for one ip address every 24 hours.
i found this tool in this link http://serials.ws.cracks.me.uk/d.php?n=8718
but i can not get the tool source, any help ?

Comment: ultimately nothing will stop the bottom feeders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to the database along with a timestamp or date and then just do a query to check the current IP and date against the number of rows it returns.

Then setup a Cronjob to cleanse your database table every night effective resetting it the same time everyday.